# Namespace with alias on Yii2 different from directory structure

Tags: namespaces, yii2, alias

I made a bunch of classes and put them inside the directory **common/a/b/c**.
So, inside file

> Class1.class.php

I have:

```
<?php
namespace x\y\b\c;
class Class1
...
```

Namespace is different from the directory structure organization, because I wanted that way. (**x\y** should map to **common/a** directory)
On my *common/config/bootstrap.php* I tried this:

```
Yii::setAlias('common', dirname(__DIR__));
Yii::setAlias('x/y', '@common/a');
```

And tried importing this class in another file using

```
use x\y\b\c\Class1;
```

With no success. But if I use:

```
Yii::$classMap['x\y\b\c\Class1'] = __DIR__ . '/../../common/a/b/c/Class1.class.php';
```

instead of **setAlias**, it works.

I wonder if it's possible to have namespace different from the directory structure without using composer and how can I do this instead of mapping every class inside **common/a/b/c**

Comment: will this work for you, Yii::setAlias('x/y', dirname(__ DIR __).'/a'); ?
change @common to the actual path.

Comment: I just tested this and Yii2 still gives me yii\base\ErrorException - Class 'x\y\b\c\Class1' not found

Comment: weird... it works on my localhost. i'll write down as an answer properly then

Comment: It could work, but the name of your file should be `Class1.php`. Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap.php.

```
Yii::setAlias('common', dirname(__DIR__));
Yii::setAlias('x/y', dirname(__DIR__).'/models');
```

Inside my "models" folder, there is folder "b" and folder "c" is inside folder "b".

```
models > b > c
```

I have a model file named "LoginForm.php" and resides in folder "c".
At the top of this file are these few lines.

```
namespace x\y\b\c;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
class LoginForm extends Model
```

Inside my SiteController I have this.

```
use x\y\b\c\LoginForm;
```

In one of the action function, i can successfully call this model.

```
$model = new LoginForm();
```

Comment: So the main problem was that all my files had the **.class.** suffix that @soju mentioned. After removing them, everything worked fine (including the `Yii::setAlias('x/y', '@common/a');`. No need to use $classMap anymore. And I can just do (following your example) `use yii\base` and the `extends Model` works just fine.