# How to use two namespaces in one file yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, namespaces

How can use two namespaces in one file yii2?

I need to use

```
namespace backend/controllers;

namespace MongoDb;
```

Comment: Go through following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723615/namespace-with-alias-on-yii2-different-from-directory-structure

Comment: I need to use `namespace MongoDB` for my calculation and that is not a model. It doen't have a directory.

Comment: You do not have to want this:)
If you need to use something form other namespace - there is keyword ```use```

Comment: Thank you @vladnev

Comment: Thank you for the reference @Gajjar

Comment: for MongoDB, just `use` is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve it like this:

```
<?php
namespace backend/controllers;

{ /* Code goes here */ }
{ /* Some more code */  }

namespace MongoDb;

{ /* Code goes here */ }
{ /* Some more code */  }
?>
```

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php